# Why are all of my results from SVM the same in scikit learn?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, libsvm

I'm trying to calculate probabilities for a multi-class dataset using scikit learn. However, for some reason, I'm getting a the same probabilities for every example. Any idea what's happening? Does this have to do with my model, my use of the library, or something else? Appreciate any help!

```
svm_model = svm.SVC(probability=True, kernel='rbf',C=1, decision_function_shape='ovr', gamma=0.001,verbose=100)
svm_model.fit(train_X,train_y)
preds= svm_model.predict_proba(test_X)
```

train_X looks like this

```
array([[2350, 5550, 2750.0, ..., 23478, 1, 3],
       [2500, 5500, 3095.5, ..., 23674, 0, 3],
       [3300, 6900, 3600.0, ..., 6529, 0, 3],
       ..., 
       [2150, 6175, 2500.0, ..., 11209, 0, 3],
       [2095, 5395, 2595.4, ..., 10070, 0, 3],
       [1650, 2850, 2000.0, ..., 25463, 1, 3]], dtype=object)
```

train_y looks like this

```
0        1
1        2
10       2
100      2
1000     2
10000    2
10001    2
10002    2
10003    2
10004    2
10005    2
10006    2
10007    2
10008    1
10009    1
1001     2
10010    2
```

test_X looks like this

```
array([[2190, 3937, 2200.5, ..., 24891, 1, 5],
       [2695, 7000, 2850.0, ..., 5491, 1, 4],
       [2950, 12000, 4039.5, ..., 22367, 0, 4],
       ..., 
       [2850, 5200, 3000.0, ..., 15576, 1, 1],
       [3200, 16000, 4100.0, ..., 1320, 0, 3],
       [2100, 3750, 2400.0, ..., 6022, 0, 1]], dtype=object)
```

My results look like

```
array([[ 0.07819139,  0.22727628,  0.69453233],
       [ 0.07819139,  0.22727628,  0.69453233],
       [ 0.07819139,  0.22727628,  0.69453233],
       ..., 
       [ 0.07819139,  0.22727628,  0.69453233],
       [ 0.07819139,  0.22727628,  0.69453233],
       [ 0.07819139,  0.22727628,  0.69453233]])
```

Comment: Why "train_y" has two columns?

Comment: Train_y has an index column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with preprocessing!.

It's very important to standardize your data to zero-mean and unit-variance.
The scikit-learn docs say [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#tips-on-practical-use):

> Support Vector Machine algorithms are not scale invariant, so it is highly recommended to scale your data. For example, scale each attribute on the input vector X to [0,1] or [-1,+1], or standardize it to have mean 0 and variance 1. Note that the same scaling must be applied to the test vector to obtain meaningful results. See section Preprocessing data for more details on scaling and normalization

- sklearns [Section on Preprocessing](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#preprocessing)
- sklearns [StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

The next step after this is parameter-tuning (C, gamma and co.). This is usually done by [GridSearch](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/grid_search.html). **But i usually expect people to try a simple LinearSVM first before trying the Kernel-SVM (less hyper-parameters, less computation-time, better generalization for non-optimal parameter-chosings)**.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do a gridsearch, but it takes a really long time. Any best practices on speeding it up.

Comment: Starting with a coarse grid of course and good initial values. Read the docs. They are very good and recommend some values depending on the classifiers. But don't do this before you repaired your preprocessing.